# imaginary equation of second degree

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the follow equation:

$$ix^2−x+2i=0$$

After resolve it with [mathway](https://www.mathway.com/) (a web that resolves the equation step by step) I can't understand the last step.
Having:

$$x=\dfrac{1\pm3}{2i}$$

I take $+2i,-i$ from "$4/2i$" and "$-2/2$". But the app say that the answer is $-2i,1$.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $\frac 1i=\frac i {i^2}=-i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple fact I think you are missing, that is that $\cfrac{1}{i} = -i$.

Hence the two solutions are $\cfrac{4}{2i} = \cfrac{2}{i} = -2i$ and similarly $\cfrac{-2}{2i} = \cfrac{-1}{i} = i$.

To understand why $\cfrac{1}{i} = -i$ take $\cfrac{1}{i}$ and multiply by $\cfrac{i}{i} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Antoher way of solving $x$:

Use the quadratic formula:

- $$ax^2+bx+c=0\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

So, solving your question, using the quadratic formula, where $a=i,b=-1,c=2i$:

$$ix^2-x+2i=0\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4\cdot i\cdot2i}}{2\cdot i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot -2}}{2i}\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8}}{2i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{9}}{2i}\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{1\pm3}{2i}$$

Answer (score 0):

You might as well divide both sides of your original equation by $i$ to get $x^2+ix+2=0$. Out of this, the quadratic formula gives you $x=(-i\pm3i)/2$, for the roots $i$ and $-2i$.